# underscore in variable name and value

Tags: jinja2

Following is a macro definition:

```
{% macro sectionListItem(anchor, name) -%}
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#{{ anchor }}">{{ name }}_ </a></li>
{%- endmacro %}
```

It's then called with:

```
{{ sectionListItem("details", _("Details")) }}
```

any idea what the underscores in `{{ name }}_` and `_("Details")` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that means you have text/strings to translate, `_()` is used as an alias to `gettext` [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html).

refer to this topic **i18n Extension**
https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/extensions/#i18n-extension

> After enabling, an application has to provide gettext and ngettext functions, either globally or when rendering. **A _() function is added as an alias to the gettext function.**

`{{ name }}_`: i have no idea about `_`, it could be a simple concatenation